# JavaScript PKCE Code Verifier (random string nonce) alternatives

Tags: nonce

I'm creating a PKCE [Code Verifier](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636#section-4.1) (a random string).

Solution 1 from a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63336562/64904). (You can copy/paste these code examples into a browser's inspector.)

```
(function generateCodeVerifier() {
    function dec2hex(dec) {
        return ("0" + dec.toString(16)).substr(-2);
    }
    
    const len = 128;
    var array = new Uint32Array( len / 2);
    window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
    return Array.from(array, dec2hex).join("");
})()
```

#### Question

Why only use the last two hex characters of the numbers?

The following uses the full numbers from the array. Is it weaker than the first solution?

I do notice that the result length of the second solution can vary depending on whether the random numbers generate leading zeros.

Question: can I pad the result for cases where the length must be exact?

```
(function generateCodeVerifier2() {
    const len = 128;
    var array = new Uint32Array( len / 8);
    window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
    return Array.from(array, x => x.toString(16)).join("");
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`generateCodeVerifier` takes a random 128-byte bytestring and converts it to hex byte by byte. `dec2hex` handles the conversion of a byte to two hex characters. The reason for prepending a `0` and taking the rightmost two characters is that if `dec` is in range [0, 15] then `dec.toString(16)` is a single character. Oh my, the web is literally littered with that idiom.

`generateCodeVerifier2` skips this normalization to two characters, thus any byte is range [0, 15] produces a single character. The average length of the output is thus 248 characters rather than 256, and the character 0 is underrepresented (proportion 1/30 rather than 1/16).

If we pad the result of `generateCodeVerifier2` to 256 characters with zeroes as considered in the question, it's non-uniform. In particular the string starts or ends with a `0` (according to the padding side) with >99.97% certainty. Since no security objective is stated in the present question, we can't tell if that's an issue or not.

In the [referred SO question](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636#section-4.1) all that matters is that the result is unique, and under that goal the non-uniformity would most likely be a non-issue: the many common ways `window.crypto.getRandomValues` could be broken (by generating the same value on different occasions, e.g. at each run, or on different machines at the same system time) are very unlikely to make `generateCodeVerifier` OK but `generateCodeVerifier2` broken from the standpoint of producing a unique value.

But said referred SO question uses the code with 28 bytes, and in that case (not the question) the non-uniformity considerably decreases the expected number of draws to reach a collision with sizable probability, assuming a truly uniform `window.crypto.getRandomValues`. It becomes at least a certificational issue.